# Trigger to populate aggregate results from child object to another child object

Tags: apex, trigger, aggregate

I want to populate aggregate results in `Funding_Cycles_TA__c` Which is a child object of `Training_Agreement__c`. The trigger is on `Training_Plan__c` which is another child object of `Training_Agreement__c`. I have written a trigger which get aggregate results successfully when updating a `Training_Plan__c` record.

Actually now I have two issues

1. The aggregate values respect to `Reporting_Year__c` (which is grouped by field in aggregate results) should be populated in respective `Reporting_Year__c` in destination object that is in `Funding_Cycles_TA__c`.
2. `achievedCredits` should be cumulative with consecutive year and populated in `Achieved_Credits_to_Rpting_Yr_End__c` (the value in `achievedCredits` should be added to the next `achievedCredits` and so on. My trigger is as below

**trigger**

```
trigger PopulateFCTAFromTP on Training_Plan__c (After Update, after insert, after delete) {

    Set<Id> TAIds = new Set<Id>();
    List< Training_Agreement__c> tasForUpdate = new List<Training_Agreement__c>();
    Training_Plan__c[] TPs = null;

    if(Trigger.isInsert||Trigger.isUpdate){
        TPs = Trigger.new;
    }else if(Trigger.isDelete){
        TPs = Trigger.old;
    }
    //select the Training plans
    for (Training_Plan__c TP : TPs) {
        if((TP.Training_Agreement__c != null) 
           ||(TP.TEC_Status__c=='Active') 
           ||(TP.TEC_Status__c=='Grace')
           ||(TP.TEC_Status__c=='Complete')
           ||(TP.TEC_Status__c=='On Hold') 
           ||(TP.TEC_Status__c=='Withdrawn')
           ||(TP.TEC_Status__c=='Pending Transfer')){
               TAIds.add(TP.Training_Agreement__c);
           }
    }
    //Aggregate SOQL from Funding_Cycles_TPS__c
    List<AggregateResult> agrResults =
        [SELECT 
         Reporting_Year__c reportingYear,
         sum(Achieved_Credits_Total__c) achievedCredits, 
         sum(Funded_Achieved_Credits__c) fundedCredits, 
         Training_Plan_Standard__r.Training_Plan__r.Training_Agreement__c ita
         FROM Funding_Cycles_TPS__c
         WHERE Training_Plan_Standard__r.Training_Plan__r.Training_Agreement__c in :TAIds 
         //where  Training_Plan_Standard__r.Training_Plan__r.Training_Agreement__c = 'a0w0M00000VpgtI' 
         GROUP BY Reporting_Year__c, Training_Plan_Standard__r.Training_Plan__r.Training_Agreement__c];

    //Corrosponding Funding_Cycles_TA__c(Child records)need to be updated from Training Agreement
    List<Funding_Cycles_TA__c>  fctasToUpdate = [Select Reporting_Year__c,
                                                Achieved_Credits_in_Rpting_Yr_Funded__c,
                                                Achieved_Credits_in_Rpting_Yr_Total__c,
                                                Achieved_Credits_to_Rpting_Yr_End__c
                                                From Funding_Cycles_TA__c
                                                where Training_Agreement__c in: TAIds order by Reporting_Year__c ];


    for (AggregateResult ar: agrResults) {
        fctasToUpdate.add(new Funding_Cycles_TA__c(Achieved_Credits_in_Rpting_Yr_Funded__c = (Decimal)ar.get('fundedCredits'), 
                                                   Achieved_Credits_in_Rpting_Yr_Total__c = (Decimal)ar.get('achievedCredits')));

    }  
    if(!tasForUpdate.isEmpty()){
        update tasForUpdate;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have shared your requirements. Where exactly you are stuck? The more easily members can understand your question, more frequently you will receive answers

Comment: I am stuck with populating aggregate results in child object Funding_Cycles_TA__c

Comment: You have fetched all **Funding_Cycles_TA__c** records in a query, so do you want to update all those record's fields with aggregate results?

Comment: Yes, But the values for Reporting_Year__c is already in the Funding_Cycles_TA__c object. I want match that value with the aggregated values. also values in Achieved_Credits_to_Rpting_Yr_End__c in Funding_Cycles_TA__c is cumulative values from Achieved_Credits_Total__c in consecutive years

Comment: I understood the first condition well, so posted the sample code in answer, please check. You can test at least first requirement. Can you please give an example of second requirement, as an example would help much better.

Comment: @JayWeera Please see my post for the answer to your 2nd part. Let me know if the understanding was correct.

Answer (score 1):

Based on comments:

You need to write a loop within loop, to match the condition for each and every record you have fetched in aggregate results. Please check the sample code below:

```
//loop within loop to match the year value on child objects.
for (AggregateResult ar: agrResults) {
    for(Funding_Cycles_TA__c FCTAToUpdate : fctasToUpdate){
        //Here is the matching condition.
        if(FCTAToUpdate.Reporting_Year__c == ar.reportingYear){
            fctasToUpdate.Achieved_Credits_in_Rpting_Yr_Total__c = (Decimal)ar.get('achievedCredits'); //populated the value.
        }
    }
} 
if(!fctasToUpdate.isEmpty()){
    update fctasToUpdate;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nitish, I get the error as Initial term of field expression must be a concrete Sobject: List on line for the second loop

Comment: Hi Nitish, I managed to sort out the above compile error and other Null value errors.  When I test this on DB I get first error: MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id not specified in an update call

Comment: I managed to get sorted all run time errors. But now the data is not populating on target object

Comment: Can you please share the code which is saved correctly. You can make edit to your question.

Comment: Hi NItish, Latest update-- I have debug the update trigger. it does not pass the loop for updating values

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood from your question - You want to add the exsisting value of `Achieved_Credits_in_Rpting_Yr_Total__c` to `sum(Achieved_Credits_Total__c) achievedCredits` and store it in `Achieved_Credits_to_Rpting_Yr_End__c`. If this is correct then you just need to use:

```
//loop within loop to match the year value on child objects.
for (AggregateResult ar: agrResults) {
    for(Funding_Cycles_TA__c FCTAToUpdate : fctasToUpdate){
        //Here is the matching condition.
        if(FCTAToUpdate.Reporting_Year__c == ar.reportingYear){
  fctasToUpdate.Achieved_Credits_to_Rpting_Yr_End__c = fctasToUpdate.Achieved_Credits_in_Rpting_Yr_Total__c + (Decimal)ar.get('achievedCredits');
  }
 }
} 
if(!fctasToUpdate.isEmpty()){
    update fctasToUpdate;
}
```